# How can I easily and quickly block domains across my whole network using a uMatrix-style visual interface?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, firewall, iptables

I am looking for a way to easily and quickly manage a list of blocked domains on my entire network.

I am aware of - and have used many tools which can do this, such as a hardware firewall, a Raspberry Pi with PiHole or even a proxy Linux box running `iptables` firewall.

The problem with these "traditional" approaches is that they take a lot of time to administer and are not very easy to maintain. Nor are they particularly useful for adding/removing rules "on the fly" i.e. when you're casually browsing the web and want to block or allow a particular domain, for example.

So I am basically looking for a way to administer a firewall (network filter, whitelist/blacklist, or whatever you want to call it) much more easily and with a more visual/interactive approach.

As an example of a solution which is limited to the sphere of web browsers, I like the way uMatrix works - it is a browser extension which allows users to filter traffic on a per-domain basis using a simple grid-like interface:

[image]

This is incredibly useful in controlling which domains are allowed to communicate with your browser, but it would be even more useful if this functionality could be extended to an entire network (covering wireless devices such as phones etc.)

Is there a way to configure something like the PiHole or a hardware firewall to have an interface like this?

Comment: Why are you asking the [same question](https://superuser.com/questions/1518736/is-there-a-way-to-apply-firewall-rules-to-an-entire-network-using-a-visual-inter) again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: @DavidPostill It's not the same question. I re-worded it and added information and "what I've tried already" as per the guideline. How would you suggest I ask this question? I really, really object to the "opinion-based answers" rule on this site. There are thousands of such questions - or ones which are even more blatantly opinion-based, or poorly written - which are allowed to remain open yet when I pose a well-written question which might actually product useful answers, it's closed as it's somehow "off-topic".

Comment: @DavidPostill In the guideline article it specifically states that a **good** example of how to ask a question could be: `"I have <problem-x> that I don't know how to solve. I've already tried X, Y, Z, but those programs don't work because this or that. How do I do this?"` That is pretty much what I've written above. Nonetheless, I shall edit my question for the **third time** to satisfy the pedantry this website demands.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have edited the question specifically following the guidelines here https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software